# Check when a number is greater than 0

Tags: javascript

I have a span with id= "availableSeats" and a button with id= "confirmButton". 
I want to check when availableSeats is greater than 0 and then remove the disabled attribute to the confirmButton.

This doesn't work:

```
function checkSeats() {
var freeSeats = document.getElementById("availableSeats").value;

if ( !(freeSeats > 0)) {
document.getElementsById("confirmButton")[0].removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); 
}
```

Comment: `if (parseInt(freeSeats) > 0)` should do the trick. The value you get from inputs are strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues:

- As your element is a `span` you should use the `textContent` property.
- As you want to interpret that value as a number, you should convert the string to number
- `getElementById` is a singular (no `s`, no array).
- The `removeAttribute` method only takes one argument.

```js
function checkSeats() {
  var freeSeats = document.getElementById("availableSeats").textContent;
//                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^
  if (+freeSeats > 0) {
//    ^^
    document.getElementById("confirmButton").removeAttribute("disabled");
//                        ^^                ^^               ^^^^^^^^
  }
}

checkSeats();
```

```html
<span id="availableSeats">10</span>

<button id="confirmButton" disabled>confirm</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you access the value of input its type is string. You need to convert it into number using Number(value) or parseInt(number)

```
if (parseInt(freeSeats) > 0) {
document.getElementsById("confirmButton")[0].removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if ( parseInt(freeSeats) > 0) {
document.getElementById('confirmButton').disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing a value of a `span` element, which hasn't a value unless you assigned it. Make it an `input` tag and it should work fine. 

For example: `<input id="availableSeats" type="number">`
Somebody can enter a number in there, and when that person presses the button, it will run your code with the value of the input.

Answer (score -1):

The value you get from input elements are always strings so you have to convert the value to a number using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` before you compare it.

```js
function checkSeats() {
  var freeSeats = document.getElementById("availableSeats").value;

  if (parseInt(freeSeats) > 0) {
    document.getElementsById("confirmButton")[0].removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); 
  }
}
```